# Contional on Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need to set A or B to Excel B7 depends on different conditional. For the following one, I should get A but I get B in B7. Anyone could help to see what is the issue please?
Condition1: B6>B3
Condition2: B3>30mins

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

& is the short form for concatenate.  You cannot have multiple condition in a single argument in excel.  The correct form for an AND function would be:

```
=IF(AND(B6>B3,B3>TIME(0,30,0)),"A","B")
```

And B3 has to be a time stored in excel format, not just text that looks like time.  You can test this with =ISNUMBER(B3) and it should return true.  If it returns false you will need to convert your time as text to an excel format.

Comment: Ah, the problem is B3... which is TEXT rather than TIME